# pyspark: rdd operation for timesteps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, bigdata, rdd

I have a file format as bellow,

```
0, Alpha,-3.9, 4, 2001-02-01 08:00:00, 5, 20
0, Beta, -3.8, 3, 2001-02-01 08:15:00, 6, 21
1, Gamma,-3.7, 8, 2001-02-01 08:30:00, 7, 22
0, Alpha,-3.5, 4, 2001-02-01 08:45:00, 8, 23
0, Alpha,-3.9, 4, 2001-02-01 09:00:00, 8, 27
0, Gamma,-3.5, 5, 2001-02-01 09:15:00, 6, 21
```

and so forth... 
I am interested in the `sum of 5th element` in each raw for a given `Alpha/Beta/Gamma` for a time interval between `08:00:00 to 09:00:00` for example. I would like to have the following result using only `rdd` based operation, `between 08:00:00 to 09:00:00`.

```
Alpha 21
Beta 6
Gamma 7
```

This is what I did for the moment;

```
rdd = sc.textFile(myDataset)
newrdd = rdd.map(myFun) # myFun process each line 
filterrdd = newrdd.filter(lambda e : e[4].startswith('2001-02-01') )
```

But I dont know how to proceed. or at least could not see a simple way to solve it using only `rdd` based operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter by time between 08:00:00-09:00:00 (inclusively), you just need to make sure the time part of this string starts with either `08:` or `09:00:00`, thus your filter function can be `e[4].split()[1].startswith(('08:', '09:00:00'))`. then you can do the regular RDD reduceByKey() etc.

```
newrdd.filter(lambda e: e[4].split()[1].startswith(('08:', '09:00:00'))) \
      .map(lambda e: (e[1], int(e[5]))) \
      .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y) \
      .collect()
#[(' Alpha', 21), (' Beta', 6), (' Gamma', 7)]
```

Comment: thanks jxc. it helps. if I want to do it from 08 to 12:00:00 in step of one hour, how should I modify?

Comment: @Mass17, what do you mean `in step of one hour`, can you add a sample with expected result?

Comment: from 08:00:00 to 12:00:00, then `('08' <= e[4].split()[1][:2] <= '11') | (e[4].split()[1] == '12:00:00')`

Comment: or convert to datetime.time object to handle any time ranges.

Comment: I meant [(' Alpha', *), (' Beta',*), (' Gamma', *)] between 8-9, [(' Alpha', *), (' Beta',*), (' Gamma', *)] between 9-10, [(' Alpha', *), (' Beta',*), (' Gamma', *)] between 10-11 and so forth..

Comment: @Mass17, can you open a new question and also clarify if `8-9` means 08:00:00-09:00:00 or 08:00:00-08:59:59, since the first one might get overlapping for multiple ranges. please also add a sample with expected result. thanks.